# Switching between windows PyQt4 Python 3.5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, python-3.5

I've looked at multiple solutions from other threads to these problems, but everything I've attempted has not worked. I'm trying to open all the frames and just simply switch between them, like you can do in tkinter.

Tkinter Code:

```
#Location Of All Frames
    Container = tk.Frame(self)
    Container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    Container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    Container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.Container = Container

    #Loop To Select Frames
    self.Frames = {}
    for F in (Login, Admin, User):
        PageName = F.__name__
        Frame = F(parent=Container, controller=self)
        self.Frames[PageName] = Frame

        #Allign Frame
        Frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

    #Call Function Show Frame
    self.show_frame(Login)

#Function To Call When Switching Frame
def show_frame(self, PageName):
    #If Instance Not Created, Create Instance
    if PageName not in self.Frames:
        self.Frames[PageName] = PageName(self.Container, self)
    Frame = self.Frames[PageName]
    Frame.tkraise()
```

I'm trying to recreate this for PyQt4, but so far have been unsuccessful. 
What I'm trying to accomplish is.

Start off with the login page.
Login(QtGui.QWidget)
And then once login, on button press. Switch to the next window.
The program is going to have many different layouts that need to be switched between.

Current Code:

```
class Application(QtGui.QMainWindow): #This was a solution from someone else that doesn't seem to work
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Application).__init__(parent)
        self.central_widget = QtGui.QStackedWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        login_widget = LoginWidget(self)
        login_widget.button.clicked.connect(self.Login)
        self.central_widget.addWidget(login_widget)

    def Login(self):
        logged_in_widget = Admin(self)
        self.central_widget.addWidget(logged_in_widget)
        self.central_widget.setCurrentWidget(logged_in_widget)
```

This method I also see as inefficient for high number of pages.

```
class LoginWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Application, self).__init__()
        self.initUI() #Call Initialize UI function

    def initUI(self):
        self.showFullScreen()
        (...)

    class Admin(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Application, self).__init__()
        self.initUI() #Call Initialize UI function

    def initUI(self):
        self.showFullScreen()
        (...)
```

I have not created any other windows yet.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: written with py2.7 may need adjustments for py3.5

Here is a solution where you use qStackedWidget, although i would recommend poping up separate dialogs since putting everything in one widget will possibly slow down your program

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys

class StackedWidget(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.resize(400, 121)
        self.page = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.stackedWidget = QtGui.QStackedWidget(Dialog)
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(Dialog)
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.page)
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.page)
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.page)
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.page)
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page)
        self.page_2 = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.verticalLayout_6 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.page_2)
        self.radioButton_2 = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.page_2)
        self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(self.radioButton_2)
        self.radioButton = QtGui.QRadioButton(self.page_2)
        self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(self.radioButton)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_2)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.stackedWidget)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)

        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText("Login")
        self.lineEdit_2.setPlaceholderText("Password")
        self.pushButton.setText("Sign-In")
        self.radioButton.setText("RadioButton")
        self.radioButton_2.setText("RadioButton")

class MultiFrameWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.ui = StackedWidget()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.signin)

    def signin(self):
        self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(int(self.ui.stackedWidget.currentIndex())+1)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = MultiFrameWidget()
widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Perfect! Believe it or not, no adjustments are needed to change to python 3.5.